# shell command to know computer manufacturing date

Tags: shell, hardware, date

as object, I would like to know when a computer was built and also last OS installation date

Comment: for kernel, `uname -a` might be a good start. `ls -l /boot` might give a clue about installation date. use `dmidecode` for hardware.

Comment: There are various manufacturing dates that are available. The CPU, RAM, and motherboard being 3 of them. Which are you looking for? A computer though perceived as a single unit is actually a collection of discrete parts that gives the illusion of a cohesive unit.

Comment: you're right sim, but we could be pretty sure that for a computer age we mean something such as Bios firmware Date and not so interested at RAM for 99% of cases

Comment: @slm, how do you get those _CPU, RAM, motherboard manufactoring dates_?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I didn't mean to imply that these dates were accessible. I'd go through tools such as `lstopo`, `lshw`, `hwinfo`, `dmidecode`, or `cpuid`. There are other tools that can extract either lowlevel info from the hardware, or can give you a part#/serial# which can be looked up to verify a components actual manuf. date.

Answer (score 9):

OS installation date is ambiguous: what counts as a new installation? If all the files are new after update, is it still the same installation? The "official" setup script may record the date, but this is distribution dependent and most distros won't do that. However, you can always check the earliest date of the files in `/bin/`, `/etc/` and `/boot/`, most of them are updated very rarely. `uname -a` will tell you about the kernel, but a lot of distros update the kernel during their updates, and `/boot/` entries with them - is a new kernel a new installation?

For hardware, it's the same problem - which part of hardware do you want to check? Motherboard is probably the best choice: the age of firmware (BIOS/EFI...).

`dmidecode` will tell you at least about the firmware - BIOS version and date is the closest to what you are asking about. A better formatted and easier to read is `lshw` which also tells you about the firmware date. Also try `hwinfo` - it doens't tell dates but could be useful someday. For hard drives, `smartctl` will tell you a lot - hard drives have self-monitoring capabilities.

Comment: I've made many updates on this distro, but it seems to me that grub information through ls -l /boot is the correct OS installation date, concerning computer built, Bios Information has it, but as you've said, if I'll upgrade its firmware could be lost by upgrade date